# javascript scrollwidth naming

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was going through the docs of el.scrollWidth

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollWidth

Any reason why it is called scrollWidth and not contentWidth ?